# GitHub Actions: Monitor a workflow run

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, monitoring

I am trying to understand what will be the best way to monitor a GitHub actions workflow.
I have a workflow that runs independently with a cron schedule and I want to monitor the runs of the workflow, I need to get an alert if the workflow didn't run for over a week.

We use Prometheus and Grafana to monitor our cloud (aws).
What do you recommend as the best solution?

I thought about sending a metrics to cloud watch on every run, but thought there might be a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor your GitHub Actions workflows and tests with [Foresight](https://runforesight.com/). It allows you to do a deep analysis of status, duration, and cost.

Disclosure: I am affiliated with the company which develops this component.